# Ability to show labels of checked serie after rendering highcharts

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, highcharts

I managed to have highcharts where through checkbox I can display value of series, if checkbox is checked or not, but now I am trying to for example right after rendering to select ( check ) first serie while rest of them are unchecked by default right after

```
this.chart =  new Highcharts.Chart(chartConf);
this.chart.series[0].selected = true;
```

But even if value is true checkbox remains unchecked, is there any way to by default have only first serie checked to true while rest of them remain unchecked ?

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {

                renderTo: 'container',

                type: 'line',

                marginRight: 130,

                marginBottom: 25

            },
            plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                   }
                 },
          line: {
            
                events: {
                    checkboxClick: function (event){
                    
                     if(event.checked)
                           {
                            var enabled = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                        this.update({
                            dataLabels:{
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        });
                        
                   return true; 
                           }
                          else{
                            var a = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                        this.update({
                            dataLabels:{
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        });
                        
                   return false; 
                           }
                     
                  },
         
                   
             },
             showInLegend: true,
               showCheckbox: true
          }
      },                
            title: {

                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',

                x: -20 //center

            },

            subtitle: {

                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',

                x: -20

            },

            xAxis: {

                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',

                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

            },

            yAxis: {

                title: {

                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'

                },

                plotLines: [{

                    value: 0,

                    width: 1,

                    color: '#808080'

                }]

            },

            tooltip: {

                formatter: function() {

                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+

                        this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';

                }

            },

            legend: {

                layout: 'vertical',

                align: 'right',

                verticalAlign: 'top',

                x: -10,

                y: 100,

                borderWidth: 0

            },
            

            series: [{

                name: 'Tokyo',

                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

            }, {

                name: 'New York',

                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]

            }, {

                name: 'Berlin',

                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]

            }, {

                name: 'London',

                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]

            }]

        });

    });

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selected: true` in your first series option like this:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
    selected: true // Here is the trick
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]} // Continue rest of your code
```

**Here is the working version of yours**

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {

                renderTo: 'container',

                type: 'line',

                marginRight: 130,

                marginBottom: 25

            },
            plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                   }
                 },
          line: {
            
                events: {
                    checkboxClick: function (event){
                    
                     if(event.checked)
                           {
                            var enabled = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                        this.update({
                            dataLabels:{
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        });
                        
                   return true; 
                           }
                          else{
                            var a = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                        this.update({
                            dataLabels:{
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        });
                        
                   return false; 
                           }
                     
                  },
         
                   
             },
             showInLegend: true,
               showCheckbox: true
          }
      },                
            title: {

                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',

                x: -20 //center

            },

            subtitle: {

                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',

                x: -20

            },

            xAxis: {

                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',

                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

            },

            yAxis: {

                title: {

                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'

                },

                plotLines: [{

                    value: 0,

                    width: 1,

                    color: '#808080'

                }]

            },

            tooltip: {

                formatter: function() {

                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+

                        this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';

                }

            },

            legend: {

                layout: 'vertical',

                align: 'right',

                verticalAlign: 'top',

                x: -10,

                y: 100,

                borderWidth: 0

            },
            

            series: [{

                name: 'Tokyo',

                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        selected: true // Here is the trick

            }, {

                name: 'New York',

                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]

            }, {

                name: 'Berlin',

                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]

            }, {

                name: 'London',

                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]

            }]

        });

    });

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

In your situation one trick is using `load` function of chart and inside of that callback function trigger your desired checkbox `click` event like the following:

```
events:{
  load: function () {
    let chs = $(".highcharts-legend-checkbox");
    if (chs && chs.length>0) chs[0].click();
  }
}
```

***And here is your working code***

```js
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {

                renderTo: 'container',

                type: 'line',

                marginRight: 130,

                marginBottom: 25,
                events:{
                      load:function(){
                          let chs = $(".highcharts-legend-checkbox");
                          if (chs && chs.length>0) chs[0].click();
                      }
                }

            },
            plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                   }
                 },
          line: {
            
                events: {
                    checkboxClick: function (event){
                    
                     if(event.checked)
                           {
                            var enabled = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                        this.update({
                            dataLabels:{
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        });
                        
                   return true; 
                           }
                          else{
                            var a = !this.options.dataLabels.enabled;
                        this.update({
                            dataLabels:{
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        });
                        
                   return false; 
                           }
                     
                  },
         
                   
             },
             showInLegend: true,
               showCheckbox: true
          }
      },                
            title: {

                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',

                x: -20 //center

            },

            subtitle: {

                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',

                x: -20

            },

            xAxis: {

                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',

                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

            },

            yAxis: {

                title: {

                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'

                },

                plotLines: [{

                    value: 0,

                    width: 1,

                    color: '#808080'

                }]

            },

            tooltip: {

                formatter: function() {

                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+

                        this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';

                }

            },

            legend: {

                layout: 'vertical',

                align: 'right',

                verticalAlign: 'top',

                x: -10,

                y: 100,

                borderWidth: 0

            },
            

            series: [{

                name: 'Tokyo',

                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

            }, {

                name: 'New York',

                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]

            }, {

                name: 'Berlin',

                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]

            }, {

                name: 'London',

                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]

            }]

        });

    });

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: That only breaks it :) I already tried that. If you try adding it on my code snippet the Tokyo in this example remains checked, to my knowledge it has to be done through function, because adding selected true breaks first serie and it remains checked forever and refuses to be unchecked.